# How can I limit INT in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, integer

I'm creating a college grading system with Java. I have a credit number column in courses table. I want this credit number to be limited between 1 to 8. I don't want any other number to be entered. I'm a beginner.

```
CREATE TABLE courses(
id INT PRIMARY KEY,
course_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
credit_number BETWEEN 1 AND 8 NOT NULL,
course_description VARCHAR(255));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `check` constraint:

```
CREATE TABLE courses (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    course_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    credit_number int NOT NULL,
    course_description VARCHAR(255),
    CONSTRAINT chk_courses_credit_number CHECK (credit_number BETWEEN 1 AND 8)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Slight variation on the accepted answer -

You could also use TINYINT instead of INT, which would restrict the possible range to -128 to 127 (one byte), which is okay since you only need 1-8:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html

```
CREATE TABLE courses (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    course_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    credit_number TINYINT NOT NULL,
    course_description VARCHAR(255),
    CONSTRAINT chk_courses_credit_number CHECK (credit_number BETWEEN 1 AND 8)
);
```

Comment: Of course, you can do this sort of constraint check.